# ElasticSearch 5.2 divides sentence with whitespaces

Tags: elasticsearch

I have the following strings:

```
"hello world"
"hello"
"hello world all"
```

and my mapping looks like this

```
...
"properties": {
  "my_field": {
    "type": "string",
    "index": "not_analyzed"
  }
}
...
```

When I try to perform a search using `simple_query_string`:

```
{
  "query": {
    "simple_query_string" : {
        "query": "hello"
    }
  }
}
```

I get all three strings.

The problem is that I need only one string which is associated with "hello".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [`term` query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-term-query.html) to get an exact match

```
{
  "query": {
    "term" : {
        "my_field": "hello"
    }
  }
}
```

Note that in ES 5, you can simplify your mapping by specifying a `keyword` type

```
"properties": {
  "my_field": {
    "type": "keyword"
  }
}
```